# How to change the html of threaded comments?

Tags: views, comments

I want to display the comments on a node in a thread.
[image: example]

Not sure if I should use views or a template.

I want to change the html so that it matches boostrap markup

By using comment-wrapper.tpl I can change some of the html,

but I cant change the indent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the default comments for the node.

Make sure threaded is enabled on the node settings page.

By installing [field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) I was able to add a div class to change the threaded comments html.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a little more info on what you are trying to do?

If you want to add your view for displaying comments to a specific thread, please take a look at using panel from contrib (https://drupal.org/project/panels).

This module allows you to add views (and other components as well) to specific pages, other panels (when using mini panels) etc...

Comment: Is the question better asked now?
I prefer to use display suite instead of panels.